# GetX (updated to 4.1.1) with FirebaseAuth - Flutter authentication not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-getx

Since updating GetX 4.1.1 my authentication model has broken.

This used to work in my code:

```
class AuthenticationService extends GetxService {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

     Rx<User> _firebaseUser = Rx<User>();   //<--error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
```

The main issue here is that 'Rx()' is now an error.  How do I fix this now that I have upgraded to GetX 4.1.1?

I've tried replacing it with User().obs but then the error is: User doesn't have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change it up like this:
Rxn  _firebaseUser = Rxn ();
See https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1241